# loop to create a new variable based on other cases in R (very basic)

Tags: r, loops, vectorization, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with three variables: `ID`, `group`, and `nominated_ID`.
I want to know the `group` that `nominated_ID` belongs in.

I'm imagining that for each case, we take `nominated_ID`, find the case where it is equal to `ID`, and then set the `nominated_Group` variable in the original case equal to the `group` variable in the matched case.  (If there is no match, set it to NA)

I wouldn't be surprised if this can be done without a loop, so I'm open-minded about the solution.  Thanks so much for your help.  Know that I did try to look for similar questions before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this in one step without the use of `cbind` by directly allocating results to a column in your data.frame:

```
df$nominated_group <- with(df, group[match(nominated_ID, ID)])
df
  ID group nominated_ID nominated_group
1  9   Odd            9             Odd
2  5   Odd            8            <NA>
3  2  Even            4            Even
4  4  Even            9             Odd
5  3   Odd            2            Even
```

I used `with` as a convenient way of referring to the columns of df without having to repeatedly write `df$`.

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work; there may be better ways

```
> df <- data.frame(ID = c(9, 5, 2, 4, 3), 
+                  group = c("Odd", "Odd", "Even", "Even", "Odd"),
+                  nominated_ID = c(9, 8, 4, 9, 2)                 )
> df
  ID group nominated_ID
1  9   Odd            9
2  5   Odd            8
3  2  Even            4
4  4  Even            9
5  3   Odd            2
> nominated_Group <- df[match(df$nominated_ID, df$ID), ]$group
> newDF <- cbind(df, nominated_Group)
> newDF
  ID group nominated_ID nominated_Group
1  9   Odd            9             Odd
2  5   Odd            8            <NA>
3  2  Even            4            Even
4  4  Even            9             Odd
5  3   Odd            2            Even
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the protocol is (and would like to be informed), but I'm leaning towards calling this the solved answer because it is both good and was first, while noting and voting up the code simplifications made by @Prasad `df <- transform( df, nominated_group = group[match(nominated_ID, ID)])` and @Andrie `df$nominated_group <- with(df, group[match(nominated_ID, ID)])`  Perhaps I can sneak in a follow-up question... how do I create a `parent_group` variable such that in all nominations occur within the same `parent_group`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in a syntactically compact way using `transform`, `match` and array indexing. Using @Henry's data-frame:

```
df <- transform( df, nominated_group = group[match(nominated_ID, ID)])

> df
  ID group nominated_ID nominated_group
1  9   Odd            9             Odd
2  5   Odd            8            <NA>
3  2  Even            4            Even
4  4  Even            9             Odd
5  3   Odd            2            Even
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most "intuitive' way, but merging `df` against `df` also works if you use nominated_ID as the merge index for the first copy and ID as the by index for the second and keep all rows. You need to drop the second `nominated_ID` column and rearrange the order to get things to match the answers above:

```
merge(df,df, by.x=3, by.y=1, all.x=TRUE)[order(df$nominated_ID), c(2,3, 1, 4)]

  ID group.x nominated_ID group.y
5  4    Even            9     Odd
3  5     Odd            8    <NA>
2  2    Even            4    Even
1  3     Odd            2    Even
4  9     Odd            9     Odd
```